# MySQL insert then update table data

Tags: java, php, mysql

Hey Ive run into a little problem in my SQL/PHP/JAVA application Im hoping you guys can help :) 
I have a java application that when run is connected to my website when the java application validates that it is running it talks to my website and my website assigns a session Id to both the java application and the website itself.

cool we good so far?

alright my java application sends data at regular intervals to a page called Dashboard.php what I would like to do is save the data into my Mysql table then when new data is received by Dashboard.php from my java application where the sessionID is the same I would like the table to update to the new data that was just received

here is the php i have so far although it doesnt work.

```
function update($script_name, $version, $runtime, $status, $ranged, $attack, $defense, $strength, $magic, $sessionID, $username)
{
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Dashboard WHERE session_id = '$sessionID'";
    try {
        $results = $db->query($sql);
        if ($results->rowCount() <= 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO Dashboard (script_name, version, runtime, status, ranged, attack, defense, strength, magic, session_id, username) VALUES ('$script_name', '$version', '$runtime', '$status', '$ranged', '$attack', '$defense', '$strength', '$magic', '$sessionID', $username)";
            $db->exec($query);
        } else {
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                $timerunnew = $row['runtime'] + $runtime;
                $v4new = $row['ranged'] + $range;
                $v5new = $row['attack'] + $attack;
                $v6new = $row['defense'] + $defense;
                $v7new = $row['strength'] + $strength;
                $v8new = $row['magic'] + $magic;
            }
            $db->exec("UPDATE Dashboard SET `runtime` = $timerunnew, `ranged` = $v4new, `attack` = $v5new, `defense` = $v6new, `strength` = $v7new, `magic` = $v8new WHERE session_id = '$sessionID'");
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "fail";
    }
}
```

Ive also tried experimenting with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)` however I have had no luck does anyone have a solution? any help would be much appreciated

Comment: In your parameter you have `$ranged` but your using `$range` on: `$v4new = $row['ranged'] + $range;`

Comment: oh wow i didnt see that let me change that and test it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only way that records can be inserted into the `Dashboard` table, then it is impossible for two records to share the same `session_id` (save for a race hazard occurring between the `SELECT` and `INSERT` commands).  In which case, you should:

1. Ensure that there is a `UNIQUE` key defined on `session_id`:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE Dashboard ADD UNIQUE KEY (session_id);
   ```
2. Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), ideally with a properly parameterised prepared statement:

   ```php
   $qry = $db->prepare('
     INSERT INTO Dashboard (
        script_name,  version,  runtime,  status,  ranged,  attack,
        defense,  strength,  magic,  session_id,  username
     ) VALUES (
       :script_name, :version, :runtime, :status, :ranged, :attack,
       :defense, :strength, :magic, :session_id, :username
     ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       runtime  = runtime  + VALUES(runtime),
       attack   = attack   + VALUES(status),
       defense  = defense  + VALUES(defense),
       strength = strength + VALUES(strength),
       magic    = magic    + VALUES(magic)
   ');

   $qry->execute([
     ':script_name' => $script_name,
     ':version'     => $version,
     ':runtime'     => $runtime,
     ':status'      => $status,
     ':ranged'      => $ranged,
     ':attack'      => $attack,
     ':$defense'    => $defense,
     ':strength'    => $strength,
     ':magic'       => $magic,
     ':session_id'  => $sessionID,
     ':username'    => $username
   ]);
   ```